# Using "time ago" Javascript function within HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the humanized_time_span from http://github.com/GrouchPotato/js_humanized_time_span

For a project I'm working on, I need a "time ago" time stamp for a list of "recent posts". My question is, can I include the humanized_time_span script within my HTML (it has to be that way, I can't use it as an external file) and how do I call the function within the HTML body? I'm pretty new with JS, so please explain in detail.

I have a UL list of these "posts" and I need to include the time stamp out beside each post.

```
<ul>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><strong>This is a random post</strong></a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><strong>This is a random post 2</strong></a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><strong>This is a random post 3</strong></a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><strong>This is a random post 4</strong></a></li>
</ul>
```

Currently, I have the code from the github repo at the end of my HTML element between script tags, but I don't know how to use that script in the HTML.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do, nor is it clear what you've tried, if anything.

Comment: It is clear, OP wants to know how they can use the JavaScript on their HTML.

Comment: Okay, it's clear to @epascarello.  But for the rest of us, please elaborate on the problem.

Comment: I've copied the script from github between script tags at the end of my HTML element, but I don't know how to use that script/function within the HTML itself.

Comment: Where is the timestamp data coming from in the HTML snipplet you provided?

Comment: There is no data because I don't know how to call the function from the script.

Comment: All I know is that "humanized_time_span("2010/09/10 10:00:00");" has to be in there somehow

Comment: Where do you get the time data from in the HTML so you can call the function? That is what I am trying to figure out so I can help you out. The data needs to be somewhere so it can be read and the function executed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would need to select the elements and run the function and replace the text.

So on document.ready or window onload you would need to select the elements, read the text, and call the function, and replace the text with what was returned.

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li strong");  //select the elements
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {  //loop over the HTML collection
  var li = lis[i],  //reference the current element of the collection
      text = li.innerHTML,  //read the text (could use textContent)
      result = humanized_time_span(text);  //run the function
  li.innerHTML = result;  //replace the text with the result returned from calling the function
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/GrouchPotato/js_humanized_time_span/master/humanized_time_span.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><strong>2016/09/13 11:00:00</strong>
  </li>
  <li><strong>2016/09/12 11:00:00</strong>
  </li>
  <li><strong>2016/09/11 11:00:00</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much for your help! I have to include the script from the github inside script tags in my html. Would I just do that in the "head"? The only other problem is that it is picking up all the text within all the li strong tags. anything that is not a date is returned Nan.

Comment: I can not help you without knowing what the text is... I asked you a couple of times what is the text that is outputted...

Comment: Ok, I've updated a couple things... I've changed the whole thing to a table. On the left of the table is the post title and on the right is the "time ago".
<tr>
     <td><strong>Did anyone watch the game...</strong></td>
<td class="text-right"><span class="date">2010/09/10 10:00:00</span></td>
</tr>

Comment: And my function is:
var time = document.querySelectorAll("date"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {  
    var date = time[i], 
      text = date.innerHTML, 
      result = humanized_time_span(text); 
  date.innerHTML = result;  
}

It's not working though. Is the span class the wrong thing to do?

Comment: because `querySelectorAll("date")` looks for `<date>` elements. Missing the period for a class selector. `".date"`

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much, such a big help!